# DocuSign REST Api String field limits

Tags: docusignapi

The DocuSign REST API has some descriptions that include the width for string fields.  But many string fields don't have a width in the description.  I have found references here and their site to some of those being 100 characters. Is there a Docusign default max length for these string fields that don't have widths defined?

The reason for this is that some data is going to be extracted, and stored in a database table for analysis.

I've gone over the Swagger, the DocuSign REST API documentation pages, and a bunch of the Stackoverflow pages.

Comment: which field specifically are you asking about?

Comment: Any field that isn't documented to have a length.  It's more of a general question because at this time my list fo fields keeps growing.  Also, I'm seeing a bunch of StackOverflow answers just saying things get truncated at 100 characters, which makes me think the limit is 100 characters.  So I'm kinda looking to validate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100 is probably a good default maximum length if you don't have any documentation saying otherwise for this specific field.

If you have a need to confirm a specific field maximum length - I can inquire about this for you. I do know this limit (100) as the right maximum for several specific fields.

Comment: A reasonable estimate of the size is good enough for us to get started, and if we happen to need more, I'll be sure to ask.  Thanks.